# Как сделать рендер добавленного объекта

Tags: reactjs, ооп, typescript, render

У меня есть доска в которой хранится двумерный массив inputOutputManager(эта нужная мне обертка для логики с item). Я немного не помаю как должен происходить новый рендер, когда добавляется inputOutputManager, в идеале конечно должен быть рендер только добавленного объекта, но я без понятия как такое должно быть реализовано.

```
import Board from '../model/board'
import InputOutputManager from '../model/inputOutputManager'
import Item from '../model/item'
import Column from './Colunm'

export default function BoardComponent() {
  const board = new Board()

  const hadleAddItem = (name: string) => {
    const item = new Item(name)
    const inputOutputManager = new InputOutputManager()
    inputOutputManager.addInputItem(item)

    board.addBlock(0, inputOutputManager)
  }

  return (
    <div className=" flex">
      <div className="flex flex-col items-start">
        <button onClick={() => hadleAddItem('iron')}>add Iron</button>
        <button onClick={() => hadleAddItem('copper')}>add Copper</button>
        <button onClick={() => hadleAddItem('iron')}>add Stone</button>
      </div>
      <div className="flex gap-10">
        {board.board.map((items) => (
          <Column items={items} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: `Board` - это обычный JS класс?

Comment: Да, **Board** это обычный класс, который я реализовал вот так
```ts
import InputOutputManager from './inputOutputManager'

class Board {
  board: InputOutputManager[][]

  constructor() {
    this.board = []

    this.createRow()
  }

  addBlock(row: number, inputOutputManager: InputOutputManager) {
    const currentRow = this.board[row]

    currentRow.push(inputOutputManager)
    this.board[row] = currentRow
  }

  createRow() {
    this.board.push([])
  }
}

export default Board
```

Comment: Если хотите нормально жить с реактом, от классов придется отказаться. В качестве хранилища данных воспользуйтесь redux или перепишите всю логику в верхнеуровневый компонент.

Answer (score 0):

Так, как ты делаешь, делать не надо в принципе.

Но если очень хочется, то простейшие костыли выглядят так:

> ```
> const board = new Board()
> ```

```
const board = useRef(new Board()).current
const [x, setX] = useState(0)
const forceUpdate = useCallback(() => setX(x => x + 1))
```

или чуть оптимальнее

```
const board = useRef(null).current ||= new Board()
const [x, setX] = useState(0)
const forceUpdate = useCallback(() => setX(x => x + 1))
```

> ```
> board.addBlock(0, inputOutputManager)
> ```

```
board.addBlock(0, inputOutputManager)
forceUpdate()
```

> ```
> <Column items={items} />
> ```

Предполагаю, что тут нет `memo` либо ссылка `items` меняется.

> рендер только добавленного объекта

1. Без рендера компонента, рендерящего список не обойтись.
2. Чтобы старые айтемы не рендерились (каждый из них в отдельности, а не весь список), надо компонент, который рендерит item, обернуть в memo, и при рендере списка не забыть им задать `key`.